# Modify variable from function

Tags: function, variables, actionscript-3

Could you give me some idea of how to give value to a variable from a function?

What I do is load the content of a txt, but I need that instead of feeding a dynamic text (that works), feed a variable that I can use outside the function. I want to give the content of the txt to the variable "textito" declared outside the function.

Any ideas?

The text "teet1" is only for a test, what I really need is to give value to the variable "textito" because I need to use it outside the function. Lo que ha

```
override public function SetData(xmlData:XML):void 
    {           
       for each (var element:XML in xmlData.children())
       {

        if (element.@id == "f0")        
          {
            var textito:String
            var f0 = element.data.@value.toString();
            var f0A:String = f0.substr(-4);
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("C:/Users/Nicolás Agüero/Desktop/Test/" + f0));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
            function onFileLoaded():void
                {
                    textito = loader.data;
                }

            teet1.text = textito;

        } 

        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't declare **var textito:String;**. If there's a local function variable with the same name as external variable, then the function will address  the local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables that need **global** access should be declared outside of any functions.

Try a setup like this:

```
public var textito :String = "";
public var loader :URLLoader;

override public function SetData(xmlData:XML) :void 
{           
    for each (var element:XML in xmlData.children())
    {
        if (element.@id == "f0")        
        {
            var f0:String = element.data.@value.toString();
            var f0A:String = f0.substr(-4);

            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
            loader.load( new URLRequest("C:/Users/Nicolás Agüero/Desktop/Test/" + f0) );
        }

    }
}

public function onFileLoaded(evt:Event) :void
{
    textito = loader.data; //can also try... evt.data ...since the Event gives Loader its data.
    teet1.text = textito;
}
```